# Can you help me cure font outlines (as opposed to the font itself) showing up in webpages?

Tags: font

I am having some issues with fonts rendering improperly across browsers. Essentially i am just getting outlines, an example can be viewed her.

[image]

For example on this page. http://book.cakephp.org/view/1442/link all of the navigation links in the teal bar appear as outlines.. as do the main nav items on the left side of the  screen. this is how my browser is showing this page

[image]

My first attempt at fixing this involved removing all duplicate fonts on my system ( there were a couple ) but that did not seem to fix it. A friend of said it was might be a conflict between Helvetica and Helvetica Neue installed but i need both of those fonts.. any suggestions?

Comment: pls, post the URL for the problematic page.

Comment: sorry. i was a bit misleading.. i say across all browsers but i am not writing code i am just talking about fonts on sites that i am browsing.

Comment: so on what site you do see the wrong rendering? Post one example site address.

Comment: k, editing the main post with a url

Comment: I was tried it and OK. And i have both Helvetica and Helvetica Neue too. So, have no idea, yet.

Comment: hmm very weird.. i guess ill have to start disabling fonts and see what fixes the problem.

Comment: I've tried to clean this up - are you still seeing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to empty your font cache and restart--and there are a variety of utilities, some free, that will do this for you.